# jQuery UI accordion is invisible in IE7 when dragged in a sortable list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, jquery-ui

Ok, so we have a simple unordered list that looks like this:

```
<ul id="list1" class="connectedSortable">
<li>
    <div id="accordion"><h3><a href="#">This is an accordion</a></h3><p>content</p></div>
</li>
```

And another unordered list that looks like:

```
<ul id="list2" class="connectedSortable">
<li>Some item</li></ul>
```

When the page loads, we do two things:

1. Connect the two lists

   ```
   $(function() {
   $( "#list1, #list2" ).sortable({
       connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
   }).disableSelection();   });
   ```
2. Make the accordion div into an accordion

   ```
   $(function() {
   $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
       collapsible: true,

   });});
   ```

This functionality works; in IE > 7, Chrome, Firefox, etc. it all works perfectly well. In <= IE7, on the other hand, dragging the accordion to the other list result in it taking up space but not being visible until the other element is dragged around.

It's a rather odd bug that is even visible by going to the [jQuery UI demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/sortable.html). Grab an element and drag it around; it should disappear until another one is moved. At least, that's what it's doing here.

What's odd is that removing style sheets completely fixes the issue in IE7 and below. The only style applied to the page is the default jQuery UI generated CSS (Redmond theme in my case).

What I want to know is what can be done to fix this behavior? I unfortunately am required to target IE7, so it must be supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into this issue myself. Turns out it was a "hasLayout" bug. For some reason in IE7 the dragged sortable item loses its hasLayout status. The fix is to force layout on it.

```
.ui-sortable li {
  zoom:1;
}
```

Where the `li` is the actual element being sorted. Could be a `div` a table's `tr` or anything else in your scenario. Or you could simply add a class to these and use that (sortable doesn't automatically add any classes to the items).

If that doesn't work for you, I went a bit nuclear and applied it to everything:

```
.ui-sortable, .ui-sortable li, .ui-sortable h3 {
    zoom:1;
}
```

(`h3` was my handle for sortable)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This issue was driving me crazy, and this fixed it for me. +1 and accepted.